# IntelliJ Idea Community Edition using excessive memory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, memory

I am new to using IntelliJ IDEA, and I am constantly getting warnings that I need to increase my max memory heap size, which is currently set to 2048M.  I developing Java applications built with Maven on a Windows desktop with 8GB of RAM. The task manager indicates that the IDE is using over 3GB of memory.

I have searched the JetBrains site for help with this and have found recommendations to remove/disable certain plugins. I did that as much as I could, and currently only have two non-standard plugins installed, one for AWS and one for Tomcat.

Even my smallest Java application exhibits this problem. I am wondering if others have faced this issue and how you have overcome it.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions; I appreciate the help!

Edit:

As I noted in my comment, it seems the memory issue stems from the project selection panel. If I have a project open and then close IntelliJ (without selecting "file/close" first), then reopen IntelliJ, the project opens up with reasonable (~800M) memory usage.  Opening a project through the project selection panel results in a memory usage of > 2,700M!

Comment: Does it help to disable AWS and one for Tomcat? They also could cause high memory consumption. If that does not help, please [post a message](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) to JetBrains Support attaching [idea.log](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#logs-directory) and [memory snapshot](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems#CPU_Snapshot_2019_2)

Comment: Hi Konstantin, thanks for your suggestion. I did try disabling both the Tomcat and the AWS plugins, but it resulted in only a modest reduction in memory.  However, I did notice something very odd.  If I have a project open, close IntelliJ entirely, then reopen the project, the memory usage is significantly lower than if I select "File/close project", close IntelliJ, then reopen to the New/Open projects panel.  Something about that panel is causing a memory issue.  I will look on the JetBrains site to see if anyone else has notice this behavior!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved!**

I was finally able to figure out the source of the major memory leak: It is the **Eclipse Interoperability** plugin.  I cycled through enabling/disabling the plugin, restarting in between attempts, and am certain that this is the problem.  Fortunately I don't need this plugin.

I can see from the JetBrains help site that there can be other sources of excessive memory use in IntelliJ, but this one resolved the problem for me.

Comment: It did not worked for me. I disabled a lot of plugins, but RAM usage is always about ~1GB

Comment: how did you know it was the biggest memory hogger plugin? I disabled it,

Answer (score 1):

**1. Clear the system cache**
From the main menu, select File | Invalidate Caches.

**2. In the Invalidate Caches dialog, you can select additional actions that the IDE will perform while removing the cache files:**

Clear file system cache and Local History: remove the virtual file system cache together with the information stored in Local History.

This action might be helpful for troubleshooting purposes when the usual cache invalidation is not enough to solve the problem.

Clear VCS Log caches and indexes: remove the cache and indexes of the VCS Log.

Enable this option if you are certain that your VCS Log indexes are broken, for example, if the Log search doesn't work correctly.

Clear downloaded shared indexes: remove the downloaded shared index files.

Ask before downloading new shared indexes: show a notification prompting you to download new shared indexes as they become available.

Enabling this option also updates your settings for shared project indexes in Settings/ Preferences | Tools | Shared Indexes.

**3.Click Invalidate and Restart.**
[You can follow this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Gfq.png)

If you click Just restart, cache files won't be deleted, and the selected optional actions won't be applied.

*We recommend that you restart the IDE via Find Action: press Ctrl+Shift+A and type Restart IDE*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Saroar, thanks for your response. Unfortunately this did not have any effect on the memory usage. It was worth a try, so I am grateful for the suggestion!